# angularjs promises use the word finally. grunt jshint complains

Tags: angularjs, jshint, grunt-contrib-watch

AngularJS allows the use of finally after the return of a promise. However, when I have a grunt-jshint running I keep getting

```
Expected an identifier and instead saw 'finally' (a reserved word).
```

Does any one know how to turn this off in jshint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**es5 option**

> This option enables syntax first defined in the ECMAScript 5.1
>   specification. This includes allowing reserved keywords as object
>   properties.

If you are using a version of jshint prior to 2.0.0, then you have the option of setting an es5 flag. Starting with 2.0.0, es5 is the default. I assume you are using an older version.

**Alternatively**

You can also say `promise['finally'](function(){});` rather than `promise.finally(function(){});`

**See**

- http://jshint.com/docs/options/#es5
- https://jslinterrors.com/expected-an-identifier-and-instead-saw-a-a-reserved-word
- http://jshint.com/blog/2013-05-07/2-0-0/

Comment: I rarely use finally, and find that the array syntax works just fine.

Comment: Starting from version 2.9.0 option es5 was deprecated. Use `esversion: 5` instead.